# GPU Memory Consumption before Render - Linux Mint 17.1

Tags: cycles-render-engine

since i switched from Windows to LinuxMint 17.1 Cinnamon, i have a problem regarding rendering with my NVIDIA 780 GTX (3GB VRAM).

I get this:
*CUDA error: Out of memory in cuArrayCreate(&handle, &desc)*

Interesting Fact: it already stops preparing the Render at ~800MB.

*nvidia-smi: Memory Usage 2115MiB / 3071MiB* **BEFORE** i even hit "Render"

On Windows, i was able to render the whole scene without any problems.
Looks like Blender is messing um my VRAM or using it wrong, any Suggestions?
Thank you!

Comment: Are you using the latest version/build of Blender? If not, try updating, and if you are, report it to the bug tracker, at developer.blender.org

Comment: It might be related with the nvidia driver you are using in Linux. Try installing the one from the Nvidia site.

Comment: using latest blender version from blender.org 2.73, also using the newest NVIDIA driver 346.47